# Controlling Sccm using CLI

Tags: sccm, sccm-2012, build-server

Is there a way to do the actions done from the SCCM console through a command line interface or powershell interface?

I am talking mainly about the creation of task sequences and installation packages.

The idea is to incorporate this in a development team's build process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. You can achieve most of GUI operations through Powershell either in ConfigMgr. Just download the ConfigMgr Powershell module [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46681).

After installing the powershell module, you can simply connect the ConfigMgr site server via Powershell and find out your desired cmdlet like below:

[image]

[image]

You can also find the online CmdLet reference [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj821733(v=sc.20).aspx).